# Если поле сущности было изменено, то поменять значение одного её столбца

Tags: sql

У меня есть сущность "Требования". Если пользователь изменил поле "Описание" в этой сущности, то должно автоматически меняться значение поля "Стабильность"(dropdownlist). То есть если Описание требования пришлось поменять, то оно становится нестабильным. Я написала триггер

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ChangeStabilityRequirement] ON [dbo].[Requirement] 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN 
  if update([Definition]) 
    begin 
      update [Requirement] set Stability = 2 
    end 
end
```

Но проблема в том, что триггер срабатывает при любом изменении записи в таблице. А нужно, чтобы реагировал только на изменение столбца "Definition".

Еще не написала, возможно, это важно: Нужно, чтобы потом была возможность вернуть поле "Стабильность" к значению "Средняя".

Comment: @Tanya, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Tanya, много вопросов.
1. 
> Но проблема в том, что триггер срабатывает при любом изменении записи в таблице.
Подозреваю, что не триггер срабатывает, а апдейт, но так и должно быть.
2. 
> Нужно, чтобы потом была возможность вернуть поле "Стабильность" к значению "Средняя".

Если в триггере вы устанавливаете значение Stability = 2, т.е. целое число, то как вы хотите вернуть значение в строку "средее", и когда это "потом"
3. При изменении любой строки ваш триггер будет апдейтить всю таблицу.
Не уверен, что вы этого хотели.  
4. Совершенно непонятно, почему за этот вопрос голосуют. :-)

Comment: 1)Я понимаю, что так должно быть, но мне в моей ситуации нужно другое
2)В таблице значение поля "Стабильность" целое число (перечисление, например 2 это "Низкая")
3)Да, мне не надо обновлять всю таблицу, но я не соображу, как переделать триггер, поэтому и обратилась за помощью.
4)Я не знаю, почему за него голосуют

Answer (score 3):

Ну наверное вот так:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER MyTrigger
on dbo.[Some] after update
AS
BEGIN 
    IF UPDATE ([First]) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Some]
        SET  Second = 10
    END 
END
```

Здесь триггер срабатывает только при обновлении столбца First, и не срабатывает при обновлении других столбцов.

Comment: К сожалению, триггер срабатывает на изменение любого столбца.
Еще не написала, возможно, это важно: Нужно, чтобы потом была возможность вернуть поле "Стабильность" к значению "Средняя".

Comment: >К сожалению триггер срабатывает на изменение любого столбца

неправда. Триггер срабатывает только на изменение столбца First. Вероятно, вы его некорректно переносите на свою бд

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER [ChangeStabilityRequirement]
 ON [dbo].[Requirement] AFTER UPDATE
 AS
 BEGIN
  if update([Definition])
  begin
   update [Requirement] set Stability = 2
  end
 end

Comment: Во-первых, боюсь, мне ваш код кол о чем говорит - мне незнакомы структура  и содержание вашей базы. Во-вторых, а вы уверены, что  корректно делаете апдейт и корректно откатываете обновленные значения после апдейта? В-третьих, отформатируйте пожалуйста код

Comment: В комм нельзя отформатировать код. Да, я уверена, что все обновленные значения корректно откатываются.

Comment: в комментариях можно форматировать код, предваряя каждую строку соответствующим отступом. Касательно триггера - он правильный, ошибка где-то у вас. К сожалению, ничего по ней сказать не могу, поскольку не знаю, как конкретно вы работаете с кодом, и что у вас за база

Comment: Обновление происходит через веб-интерфейс. Я с помощью SQL Server Profiler нашла запрос, который происходит при обновлении записи.

`exec [dbo].[Requirement_Update] 
@RequirementId=32,
@Definition=N'Реализовать возможность выбора значения "Без пени" в поле "Тип начисления пени". Диалоговое окно АР-12',
@Rationale=N'В соответствии с изменением бизнес-правила',
@CreatedOn='2014-12-18 00:00:00',
@State=0,
@Stability=1`

 Обновила я только один столбец, а в запросе указано обновление всех столбцов. Поэтому триггер и срабатывает при изменении любого столбца.